# Using Linq to query objects from a database and checking if they exit in a another list or array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

UPDATE: Here's what I'm trying to accomplish. My view has a text box and a search button. Once a search parameter is entered and the button is clicked the textbox and the button are hidden and the results show on that same view. Should I be doing this differently (another view perhaps)? Because I'm getting the following error

NotSupportedException: Could not parse expression '__words_0.Any(Convert(Boolean Contains(System.String).CreateDelegate(System.Func`2[System.String,System.Boolean], job.Description)))': The given arguments did not match the expected arguments: Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.

it's complaining about the following line  @if (!Model.Any())

View

```
@model IEnumerable<TheVesume.Jobs>

<div id="search" class="search">
    @if (!Model.Any())
    {
    <form>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <h4>What</h4>
                <p>@Html.TextBox("SearchString")</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="submit" value="Find" class="btn btn-default">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    }

    @if (Model.Any())
    {
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </div>
        }
    }

</div>
```

I'm trying to create a Job Search website and I need a way to search the job table in my database. I'm using entity framework. Here's what I have so far

Model

```
public partial class Jobs
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Requirements { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public IActionResult Index(string searchString)
{
    var query = from t in db.Jobs
                select t;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        var strings = searchString.Split(' ');
    }
    return View(whatever);
}
```

I need to return everything from the query that contains any of the strings in the searchString to the View. So if the searchString is in the Title or Description or Requirements. I'm new to linq please help.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a good start. It's not case-insensitive like you may want to have it, it's not culturally independent, but it should give you an idea.

```
public IActionResult Index(string searchString)
{
    var query = from t in db.Jobs
                select t;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        return View(query);
    }

    var words = searchString.Split(' ');

    var jobsMatching = query.Where(job => words.Any(job.Description.Contains)
                                       || words.Any(job.Title.Contains)
                                       || words.Any(job.Requirements.Contains));

    return View(jobsMatching);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to search your searchString into Title, Description and Requirements not the other way around looking for title, description and requirement in searchString

You can use this helper predicate builder class to build Or/And query

```C#
public static class PredicateBuilder
    {
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                            Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
        {
            var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                  (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
        }

        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                             Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
        {
            var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                  (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
        }
    }
```

And using above predicate helper you can build below predicate and pass it on to linq expression

```C#
 var searchStrings = searchString.Split(' ');
```

```C#
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Jobs>();

                foreach (var searchStr in searchStrings)
                {
                   predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Title.Contains(searchStr) || p.Description.Contains(searchStr) || p.Requirements.Contains(searchStr));

                }
```

```C#
var jobsMatching = query.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This works great. I'm new to linq and collections so would you be able to explain the PredicateBuilder to me. I thought there would be an easier way to do this but I couldn't find anything. I also noticed that if I pass in one item in the searchString with a space it will return all the results. How can I fix this ? Thanks again.

Comment: I fixed the issue with the space by adding an if statement I was just passing the wrong parameter before. If you can explain the PredicateBuilder to me it would be great. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @LauraBejjani you might want to go through this article http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx to understand more about predicates and predicate expression builder.